# Help on imsart.cls: correctly creating list of figures

Tags: floats

I am having trouble generating List of Figures correctly with the class "imart.cls". The basic command "\listoffigures" creates the following, see, snapshot:
[image]

Could you please help saparate "List of Figures" from the itemization? Thanks a lot!

Here are the codes:

```
\documentclass[preprint,aos]{imsart}

\usepackage{float,geometry,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

Figure 1:

\begin{figure}[H]

\begin{center}

\includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight, width=1\textwidth]{ListOfFigs.pdf}
\caption[Wrong formatting: eg 1]{Wrong formatting.}

\end{center}

\label{Figc4e}

\end{figure}

Same Figure:

\begin{figure}[H]

\begin{center}

\includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight, width=1\textwidth]{ListOfFigs.pdf}
\caption[Wrong formatting: same eg]{Wrong formatting.}

\end{center}

\label{Figc4e}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Well, the class `imsart.cls` seems to be non-standard, and it seems to be the root of the troubles. You either have to provide us a link to the class file, or ask its creator to fix the bug.

Comment: Hi, tohecz, thank you very much for looking into this. The link for the imsart.cls file is : http://www.e-publications.org/ims/support/ims-instructions.html

Comment: Well, it seems that using package "tocloft" to override settings in imsart.cls works (but not in the original way)

Answer (score 1):

Section titles in `imsart` are run in; this conflicts with how the list of figures is made. A solution is to add something that will make the section title for the list of figures in a line by itself.

```
\documentclass[preprint,aos]{imsart}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}
 {\@starttoc}
 {\mbox{}\par\@starttoc}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{A title}
Some text to see what happens

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight, width=1\textwidth]{ListOfFigs.pdf}
\caption[Wrong formatting: eg 1]{Wrong formatting.}\label{Figc4e}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Avoid the `[H]` option. Also, the `center` environment should not be used inside `figure`, but the simple declaration `\centering`. This also solves the problem of the `\label` not referencing to the right number.

Note that the `demo` option to `graphicx` is just for preparing the example, don't use it yourself.

[image]

If you *really* want to change the header of the list of figures to be in small caps and centered, here's a (terrible) hack.

```
\documentclass[preprint,aos]{imsart}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}
 {\@starttoc}
 {\mbox{}\par\@starttoc}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{%
  \hskip 0pt plus 1filll\relax\normalfont\scshape List of figures\hskip 0pt plus 1filll\null\relax
}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\makeatletter\@autosecdotfalse\makeatother
\listoffigures
\endgroup

\section{A title}
Some text to see what happens

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight, width=1\textwidth]{ListOfFigs.pdf}
\caption[Wrong formatting: eg 1]{Wrong formatting.}\label{Figc4e}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I recommend you not using `imsart` for other than submissions to a journal the class supports.

Comment: Hi, Egreg, Could you please make "List of Figures." into (a) all uppercase, for which the first letter of each word is bigger than the rest, (b) centered, (c) without the last period? Thank you very much.

Comment: @CheeChen I added a hack, but I don't think you should use it.